# Country Dropdown change creates error

Tags: forms, kentico

When visiting this page: http://www.fluidcomponents.com/support/contact-us-europe
and changing the country select dropdown, it breaks, and redirects to an error page. Anyone have any ideas?

The error from the logs is below:

```
Exception type: InvalidOperationException
Exception message: The script tag registered for type 'System.String' and key 'p_lt_ctl13_Javascriptinlinescript' has invalid characters outside of the script tags:
<!--. Only properly formatted script tags can be registered.
at System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.CheckScriptTagTweenSpace(RegisteredScript entry, String text, Int32 start, Int32 length)
at System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.WriteScriptWithTags(HtmlTextWriter writer, String token, RegisteredScript activeRegistration)
at System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.RenderActiveScriptBlocks(List`1 updatePanels, HtmlTextWriter writer, String token, List`1 scriptRegistrations)
at System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.RenderActiveScripts(List`1 updatePanels, HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.ProcessScriptRegistration(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.RenderPageCallback(HtmlTextWriter writer, Control pageControl)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at CMS.UIControls.ContentPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Request information:
Request URL: http://www.fluidcomponents.com/CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx?aliaspath=/Support/Contact-Us-Europe
Request path: /CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx
User host address: 107.142.156.65
User:
Is authenticated: False
Authentication Type:
Thread account name: EP264\fluidcomponent_web
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your form control for the drop down menu is broken (customized). I would first try reproducing this issue on a "Test" page with a very simple form with just a drop down list field. If you get the same error then you should take a look at user control behind this drop down menu and investigate it directly. You can find out the file in Form controls application.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yea, I tested this on a standalone test page with a new simple form as suggested and got the same error. 
There is also a dev environment of this site where the form works, but the live site's configuration and other things have changed which I am not exactly sure what. The dev site is at: http://64.87.8.188/support/contact-us-europe

I looked at the code behind file of the form control as suggested: CMSFormControls/CountrySelector.ascx and compared it to the dev file and  everything was the same. I don't know what to do at this point...

Comment: Turning off error reporting / redirects in IIS at least fixed it so it doesn't break completely, but there is still errors in debugger when selecting country: ScriptResource.axd?d=_lVYbrIGxuy3Mob4y6zV1n22Sik_zTV2tB7vK-DYxrpbW1R6WbtWVUThBFD-U1XQFsXX9PpTkJW-dw…:2 Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

Comment: Can you share the code of the control?